# Story where people sacrifice themselves like human candles as the sun comes near

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm trying to track down a story which I think was published in the last ten years (feels like less) which I think I read in Interzone, but I can't find it in my collection. I guess I could've read it somewhere else (Fantasy and SF Magazine?) but I can't think where.

It concerns a bizarre sort of future cult of people on a moon/asteroid who basically give themselves up to God by allowing a (very) nearby sun to ignite them in a kind of Let There Be Light moment. Very vivid story, great idea, weird to read

Comment: Just to say, this is Cyberstar by Val Nolan. Published in Interzone 280, March - April 2019.